# Any way to update JSON object locally on check-in web application?

Tags: javascript, json

I learned how to write `JSON` object from local `csv` file. However, I am designing a simple check-in web application with javascript and I want to update json file locally. I asked `SO` community how to update json object in javascript and people suggests using `NodeJS` express framework which is totally new and complicated to me. I am thinking what if I can simply update json object locally, and want to learn efficient javascript solution on this task.

Basically I have local mother json file use it as simple database to check the record, and I have source `csv` file that can be written as new json object, so my program want to compare the record in new json object from mother json file.

**here is what I tried**:

in this script, I am able to write and print out `JSON` object on the console from local `csv` file, and I am able to check whether manually entered record are in json object or not.

```js
document.getElementById('uinInput').onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    checkId();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}

function checkId() {
  var typedUIN = document.getElementById('uinInput').value;
  console.log(typedUIN.length);
  if (typedUIN.length == 9) {

    loadDoc(typedUIN);

  }
}

function loadDoc(uinNum) {
  console.log(uinNum);
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var jsonString = JSON.stringify(this.responseText, null, 4);
      console.log(json);
      var i;

      /* Searches the JSON file for matching UIN number */
      for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        /* When match is found, display information about the user associated to the UIN */
        if (json[i].uin == uinNum) {
          json[i].studentInfo["checkin"] = true;
          document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML = "<u>User Info: </u>";
          document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML += "<br>Name: " + json[i].studentInfo["firstName"] + " " + json[i].studentInfo["middleName"] + " " + json[i].studentInfo["lastName"];
          document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML += "<br>UIN: " + json[i].uin;
          document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML += "<br>RSVP: " + json[i].studentInfo["rsvpStatus"];
          break; //Match is found, stop search
        } else {
          document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML = "<u>User Info: </u>" + "** User Not Found **";
        }
      }
      console.log(json)
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/extempl/40cc998d1624dd0130871a3c5f1d0256/raw/2136b294baff1f7b611523dce91c5e9b8006d7e2/test.json", true); //opens and gets the contents from json file
  xhttp.send();
}
// convert csv2json
function convertToJson(inputCsv) {
  const arrayCsv = inputCsv.split(',').map(s => s.replace(/"/gi, '').trim())
  const outputJson = [];

  for (let i = 6; i < arrayCsv.length; i += 6) {
    const [date, firstName, middleName, lastName, uin, rsvpStatus] =
    arrayCsv.slice(i, i + 6)
    outputJson.push({
      uin,
      studentInfo: {
        firstName,
        middleName,
        lastName,
        rsvpStatus
      }
    });
  }
  return outputJson;
}
/* Input CSV data needs to be written as new json object*/
const csv = `"Timestamp", "Enter First Name:", "Enter Middle Initial", 
    "Enter Last Name:", "Enter UIN:", "Are you attending the event?",
    "2019/02/22 12:41:56 PM CST", "Jonathan", "Samson", "Rowe", "123456789", 
    "No", "2019/02/22 12:44:56 PM CST", "phil", "Aspilla", "beltran", "123456788", 
    "Yes"`
const json = convertToJson(csv);
console.log(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Manually enter UIN if card swipe not applicable:</p>
  <form id="manualForm">
    UIN:<br>
    <input type="text" id="uinInput" value="" required minLength="9" maxLength="9">
    <br>
    <button id="checkinBtn" type="button" onclick="checkId()">Manual Checkin</button>
  </form>
  <p>Select local CSV File:</p>
  <input id="csv" type="file">
  <output id="out"> input file content</output>
  
  <div id = "userInfo" ><u>User Info: </u></div>
</body>
```

I am new to javascript web development and I want to learn rather simple solution. Can anyone point me out how to make this happen? Any idea? Thanks

**update**:

updated new JSON object can be integrated with mother JSON file at the end because I created template JSON object to store user data which ultimately written as `csv` file.

Comment: where is the code which will do the comparison ?

Comment: Could you add some simple json entries expectations/reality? Like we have `this json` and I want to have `this json` after `these actions`. Where it should go then? Is mother json should be modified or a new json should be created?

Comment: @extempl yeah whenever I finished updating json object (the one that converted from csv) then I allow the user to download as csv. I am new to web dev, your possible help would be appreciated.

Comment: So the question is in updating json before writing to the output file, correct?

Comment: Just replace your `for` loop with it and you'll get modified json output in the console. You can do with it whatever you want - use it as an input for CSV generation, for example or parse and output or download as a json.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/extempl/jwa4oet5/ just replaced the for loop - works for me. 
missing entry also adding with my code but with empty `studentInfo` object. Fill it with whatever information you want, is it also an issue for you?

Comment: Have no any idea, I used this file and works well: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/extempl/40cc998d1624dd0130871a3c5f1d0256/raw/2136b294baff1f7b611523dce91c5e9b8006d7e2/test.csv

Comment: Note that on my example there is no HTML output - see console.

Comment: @extempl how can I add new field such as `rsvpStatus` as `false` and `checkin` as `true` when UIN not found? any idea?

Comment: @beyond_inifinity put both here: https://d3a1eqpdtt5fg4.cloudfront.net/items/0n3j1A0s1F3D1T0Y1p0K/%5Bf0b4c64a541c7ee1920fe713c5ba1c25%5D_Image+2019-03-22+at+12.29.01.png?v=196d00b9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `for`:

```
var foundEntry = json.find(function (row) {
  return row.uin == uinNum;
} )

if (foundEntry) {
  foundEntry.studentInfo["checkin"] = true;
} else {
  json.push({
    uin: uinNum.toString(),
    studentInfo: {} //  empty object, you can fill it with data you need
  })
}

console.log(json) // result of the modifying you can use for further CSV generation.
```

like this:

```js
document.getElementById('uinInput').onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    checkId();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}

function checkId() {
  var typedUIN = document.getElementById('uinInput').value;
  console.log(typedUIN.length);
  if (typedUIN.length == 9) {

    loadDoc(typedUIN);

  }
}

function loadDoc(uinNum) {
  console.log(uinNum);
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var jsonString = JSON.stringify(this.responseText, null, 4);
      console.log(json);
      var i;

      /* Searches the JSON file for matching UIN number */
      var foundEntry = json.find(function(row) {
        return row.uin == uinNum;
      })

      if (foundEntry) {
        foundEntry.studentInfo["checkin"] = true;
        document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML = "<u>User Info: </u>";
          document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML += "<br>Name: " + foundEntry.studentInfo["firstName"] + " " + foundEntry.studentInfo["middleName"] + " " + foundEntry.studentInfo["lastName"];
          document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML += "<br>UIN: " + foundEntry.uin;
          document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML += "<br>RSVP: " + foundEntry.studentInfo["rsvpStatus"];
      } else {
        json.push({
          uin: uinNum.toString(),
          studentInfo: {} //  empty object, you can fill it with data you need
        });
        document.getElementById("userInfo").innerHTML = "<u>User Info: </u>" + "** User Not Found **";
      }
      
      console.log(json)
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/extempl/40cc998d1624dd0130871a3c5f1d0256/raw/2136b294baff1f7b611523dce91c5e9b8006d7e2/test.json", true); //opens and gets the contents from json file
  xhttp.send();
}
// convert csv2json
function convertToJson(inputCsv) {
  const arrayCsv = inputCsv.split(',').map(s => s.replace(/"/gi, '').trim())
  const outputJson = [];

  for (let i = 6; i < arrayCsv.length; i += 6) {
    const [date, firstName, middleName, lastName, uin, rsvpStatus] =
    arrayCsv.slice(i, i + 6)
    outputJson.push({
      uin,
      studentInfo: {
        firstName,
        middleName,
        lastName,
        rsvpStatus
      }
    });
  }
  return outputJson;
}
/* Input CSV data needs to be written as new json object*/
const csv = `"Timestamp", "Enter First Name:", "Enter Middle Initial", 
    "Enter Last Name:", "Enter UIN:", "Are you attending the event?",
    "2019/02/22 12:41:56 PM CST", "Jonathan", "Samson", "Rowe", "123456789", 
    "No", "2019/02/22 12:44:56 PM CST", "phil", "Aspilla", "beltran", "123456788", 
    "Yes"`
const json = convertToJson(csv);
console.log(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Manually enter UIN if card swipe not applicable:</p>
  <form id="manualForm">
    UIN:<br>
    <input type="text" id="uinInput" value="" required minLength="9" maxLength="9">
    <br>
    <button id="checkinBtn" type="button" onclick="checkId()">Manual Checkin</button>
  </form>
  <p>Select local CSV File:</p>
  <input id="csv" type="file">
  <output id="out"> input file content</output>

  <div id="userInfo"><u>User Info: </u></div>
</body>
```

Comment: before accepting your solution, would you mind to resolve me doubts? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @beyond_inifinity Check my snippet above, you'll see console output in the result window, also I fixed html result output as it was in original question. 
> `Pluse I want to update json file` It is not a json file. It is a json object. You can use it to generate the result CSV file. 
You ask too many different questions in a single issue and now it looks like `do some code for me`. This is not the place for it. We can help to clean roadblock, but you should do your work yourself. Also, you should definitely learn some basics before moving forward.

Comment: @beyond_inifinity Consider clicking on a `Full page` link (after `Run code snippet`) to expand result window, as console output overlaps the html form.